# Автоматический механический клик по button при входе на страницу

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Как можно реализовать автоматический механический клик по `button id="winterfell"` при входе на страницу?Механический,в том смысле,чтобы после входа на страницу и автоматического клика по `button id="winterfell"` все события привязанные к кнопке срабатывали

Answer (score 1):

Вот небольшой пример. В этом случае имитируется клик по кнопке через 3 секунды.

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  $('button').trigger('click');
}, 3000);

$('button').click(function() {console.log('click')})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Привет</button>
```

Comment: Не работает как надо

Comment: Я и использую clipboard.js для копирования адреса страницы нажатием кнопку,при этом выскакивает alert.Вот и сообщение появляется,а ссылка не копируется

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Демонстрация простого клика
$('.test').on('click', function () { 
  console.log($(this).text());
});

// Демонстрация триггера
$('.trigger').on('click', function () { 
  $('.test').trigger('click');
});

// Демонстрация триггера по таймеру при загрузке страницы 
setTimeout(() => {
  $('.test').trigger('click');
}, 0);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="test">Тест 1</button>
<button class="test">Тест 2</button>
<button class="test">Тест 3</button>
<hr>
<button class="trigger">Кликнуть все кнопки</button>
```

Comment: Вы можете проверить,будет ли это работать с этим http://gnatkovsky.com.ua/kak-skopirovat-adres-stranicy-v-bufer-obmena.html ?

Comment: @Matel что вы хотите сделать? Хотите перейти по ссылке и чтобы клацнулась кнопка?

Comment: ну да...с этим http://gnatkovsky.com.ua/kak-skopirovat-adres-stranicy-v-bufer-obmena.html,но работает все равно не так

Comment: @Matel https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tampermonkey

Comment: @Matel вы не можете самостоятельно поставить приложуху и вставить скрипт?